# Possible to use Subversion without a Host? That is, locally

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am starting a small project in Eclipse(plus Tigris) and I'd like to try out Subversion on it. I don't have any repository on the web.

Do I need to have a repository on the web to be able to use source control? From what I've been looking all Eclipse allows me to do is to either checkout from a Host or add a new repository (from a Host).

I've been using Mercurial for a while and all I needed was to do a `folder_name init` to add that folder to source control. How to do the same with Subversion?

Comment: Subversion is quite capable of using file-based repositories. If I remembered how to set it up I'd leave an answer.

Comment: I would suggest you stick with mercurial instead of switching to SVN.

Comment: I'll have to use it in a big project I'm going to have to work with. So I better learn how to use it well!

Comment: Ok, then you should just go ahead and create a local repository as described in the link provided by RB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
svnadmin create xyz
```

The URL will be, for example, file:///home/yourusername/xyz

Answer (score 6):

Subversion makes this easy. You can create a local repository on your system and reference it using file:// paths.

See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-commandline for how to create using either the TortoiseSVN GUI, or the command-line.

**NOTE** TortoiseSVN is a graphical front-end for Subversion, implemented as a Windows Explorer extension. It makes lots of common Subversion tasks really painless. Subversion of course ships with a command-line client so it's your choice which to use.

Comment: I've created manually through tortoise a repository on "D:/trash/svntests". I've trying adding that repository through Eclipse with "file://D:/trash/svntests" but it doesn't recognize it. What am I doing wrong? I'm on windows, if that makes a difference.

Comment: try file:///D:/trash/svntests (one more slash after file:)

Comment: Can you check-out that repository to a folder using TortoiseSVN? Hopefully we can narrow it down to an Eclipse question or an SVN question...

Comment: if your local repo path is "C:\SVNrepository" use "file:///C|/SVNrepository/"  (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  I have subversion set up on my home computer with a local repositry and the server installed as a service.  The URLs you use then point to localhost 127.0.0.0 instead of an external web address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into GIT. That doesn't require a server. http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use VisualSVN and it works like a charm. It takes like 3 minutes from when you download it to when it's working in eclipse (assuming you have subclipse installed already and whatnot.)

www.visualsvn.com

Comment: From what i'm seeing it seems VisualSVN seems to work only with Visual Studio?

Comment: not at all. It's a subversion server, so it works with anything that works with subversion.

Comment: It IS for windows. I don't know if that's a problem or not.

Comment: it' a subversion server but not an eclipse integrated tool (at least from what the site shows : "VisualSVN makes your life easier with a reliable plug-in that integrates Subversion seamlessly with Visual Studio. " )

Comment: This is what I said in my post with "Assuming you have subclipse installed already" - You asked "Do I need to have a repository on the web to be able to use source control?" and the answer is no, you can run a server on your local machine and use the repository on that.